# I need help in unit testing. for the code. I want to cover this code in angular spec file by writing unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need help in unit testing. for the code. I want to cover this code in angular spec file by writing unit test

```
loadRefreshStatus(apiUrl, actionItemParam, httpGetOptions): void {

    for (const val of actionItemParam) {
      for (const inventory of this.inventory) {
        if (val.SID === inventory.SID) {
          inventory.Status = 'Refreshing';
          this.loadSucceeded(this.inventory);
        }
      }
      this.http.get(apiUrl + '/' + val.ProviderId + '/' + val.SID + '/info', httpGetOptions).map(data => data).subscribe(data => {
        const resData = data;
        for (const inventory of this.inventory) {
          if (resData.SID === inventory.SID) {
            inventory.Status = resData.status;
            //Delux table is losing context here and hence change detation is not working.
            //Ensuring that delux table gets the context back
            const dt = document.getElementById('inventory-listing_carbon-data-table-deluxe'); //ID of delux data table
            dt.click(); //restoring context back
            this.loadSucceeded(this.inventory);
          }
        }
      },
      errresourceData => {
        this.handleError(errresourceData)
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Check this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html), hope it will be helpful

Comment: Have you looked through the testing docs on angular.io? https://angular.io/guide/testing https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: @Sayed : First of all, move the `http` call to a service. and  then update the code and let us know. YOu can refer to https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7 . There are 4 more links attached at the bottom of the article that can help you solve this. Specially https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49

Comment: @ShashankVivek, i need your help on this.

Comment: Move your `this.http.get` to a service, make changes in component file and then share the `spec` file of that component.